# Value return null when search a value using query firebase android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to ask, so I want to search a value which are an ID barcode on firebase. I try search on stackoverflow which using this line code.

```
 tindakan = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tindakan");
 bedahMulut = tindakan.child("Bedah Mulut");

 Query searchByID = tindakan.orderByChild("ID").equalTo(idBarcode);

 searchByID.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         for (DataSnapshot idSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
             Log.v("hasil", "Found! -> " + idSnapshot.child("ID").getValue(String.class));
         }
     }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
         Log.v("hasil", databaseError.toException().toString());
     }
 });
```

but this code are return `null` value, I already post structure firebase and debug session in below. Please help me in advance, thank you :)

[image: here is structure on firebase]

[image: Debug session, that are showing null value]

Comment: Can you expand your database to show `ID` for **Bedah Mulut**? Beside this `tindakan` and `bedahMulut` don't have children like `ID` which is accessible through `orderByChild`

Comment: Please add what Md. Asaduzzaman asked for and please also respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to query a deeply nested data structure, which is not possible. Firebase Realtime Database queries operate on a flat list, where the property/value you order/filter on is at a fixed path under each direct child node.

The solution is typically to create an additional data structure, where you keep a simple list of IDs and then the value is the path of the node that has that ID.

```
"IDs": {
  "INLAY": "/tindakan/Konservasi/Inlay/Kelas -"
}
```

See

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Correct JSON structure to filter through data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58151590/correct-json-structure-to-filter-through-data)
- [Firebase Query all users with nested childs , with conditions (Nodejs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54478025/firebase-query-all-users-with-nested-childs-with-conditions-nodejs/54482771#54482771)
- [Firebase query orderByChild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54372135/firebase-query-orderbychild/54373285#54373285)
- [How does .indexOn works with users and unique keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60221546/how-does-indexon-works-with-users-and-unique-keys/60229824#60229824)

Comment: If the structure like that, can I listing only just the name? Because on the project I can see (by name for example inlay (not an ID barcode)), add, update, and remove the data.

Comment: For example if I want to edit, it must show the name first (for example inlay) and then show the class and the show all information (like ID, name, price)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking there. But the structure can be whatever you want to look up, or search on. The structure in this answer makes it easy to find the path(s) for `INLAY`, but there are many other variants in the questions I linked.

Comment: And then user can update the data or remove the data. If user want to add another data it will go to another section.

Comment: So you recommend is to ID first then explain the rest? Which I must split the string to get each information? Right?

Comment: Because it's not only search the data

Comment: I already try using your method and it WORKS for all function like create, update, even delete from firebase! Do you have any suggestion or can you tell me, how to choose to be parent (for example in this case you choose "ID" as parent)?

Comment: I already check the mark, but I can't up vote because my reputation below 15